# Attempt to read-only access to Adobe Subversion repo fails (seeking BlazeDS tagged versions)

Tags: blazeds

I'm trying to download a tagged version of BlazeDS and towards that end I would like to browse the Subversion repo for the BlazeDS project. However I have tried the obvious `http://opensource.adobe.com/svn/opensource/blazeds` (as indicated on [one of the Open @ Adobe project pages at Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/adobe/blazeds/wiki/Source/)) but I get a challenge for a user name and password. Tried my SF username/pw, didn't work (didn't expect it to). Tried to go to `http://opensource.adobe.com` to see if I could register there, but got redirected back to Sourceforge. What is an appropriate username/pw? Or is there another URL I can try? The Open @ Adobe project pages at Sourceforge are pretty disorganized.

If there is a more appropriate forum for this question, by all means, please let me know. 
There doesn't seem to be a user forum for Open @ Adobe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe has donated BlazeDS to the Apache Flex community, and the source code is hosted on the Apache Flex website in a GIT repository.

http://flex.apache.org/dev-sourcecode.html

There is a forum with a commits section for BlazeDS that might add a historical viewpoint on the previous code changes, but it does appear that Apache only received a commit of the latest release, and started editing from there.

https://forums.adobe.com/community/opensource/blazeds
https://forums.adobe.com/community/opensource/blazeds/commits